async invalidate filter QSortFilterProxyModel
Создал класс, унаследованный от QSortFilterProxyModel. Я также cбрасываю фильтрацию при смене режима фильтрации. Но программа вылетает в строке без подробного описания ошибки на строке invalidateFilter, в чем может быть причина
Сброс фильтра выполняю асинхронно, чтобы UI не зависал во время фильтрации.
Когда фильтрация закончится бросаю сигнал для UI
  QObject::connect(&_watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(filterFinishedPreProcessing()));

void MyModel::filterFinishedPreProcessing()
{
  endResetModel();
  emit(filterFinished());
}

void MyModel::applyFilter()
{
  if(_watcher.isRunning())
  {
    return;
  }
  beginResetModel();
  _filter.clear();
  _filter.append(_conditions);
  cacheSourceRowCount();
  setFilterProgress(0);
  _future = QtConcurrent::run([this]() mutable { invalidateFilter(); });
  _watcher.setFuture(_future);
}


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Переведите пожалуйста текст вопроса на русский язык [edit], либо задайте ваш вопрос на en.SO //как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Методы большинства классов qt не могут быть корректно вызваны из разных потоков. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/thread-basics.html

А как в таком случае мне фильтровать модель, чтобы UI не зависал?

Я привел ссылку.
